# Why are my values always NaN with small focal length?

Tags: c++, opencv, nan

Whenever I use my camera focal length in the openCv Posit function I get NaN for all values but when i use a higher one i do not have this error (but the numbers are not true then). I have a pyramid as a model. 3 Points in 1 plane and 1 in the center above. Anyone knows how to handle this? Or some good links?

```
int depth = -18; 

//create the model points 
std::vector<CvPoint3D32f> modelPoints; 
modelPoints.push_back(cvPoint3D32f(  0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f));  //(the first must be 0,0,0) middle center diod 
modelPoints.push_back(cvPoint3D32f(-18.0f, -30.0f, depth)); //bottom left diode
modelPoints.push_back(cvPoint3D32f( 18.0f, -30.0f, depth)); //bottom right diode
modelPoints.push_back(cvPoint3D32f( 0.0f,  30.0f, depth)); //top center diode


system("cls");
//create the image points
std::vector<CvPoint2D32f> srcImagePoints;
cout << "Source Image Points:" << endl;
for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
{
    cout << "x: " << cvRound(circles[i][0]) << " y: " << cvRound(circles[i][1]) << endl;
    //228, 278
    //291, 346 (Pixel coordinates of the points on the image)
    //371, 346
    //228, 206
    srcImagePoints.push_back( cvPoint2D32f(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1])) );
}

cout << endl;

//create the POSIT object with the model points 
CvPOSITObject* positObject = cvCreatePOSITObject( &modelPoints[0], (int)modelPoints.size() ); 

//calculate the orientation 
float* rotation_matrix = new float[9]; 
float* translation_vector = new float[3]; 

CvTermCriteria criteria = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1.0e-4f); 
double FOCAL_LENGTH = 16; //16.0; //760.0; 
cvPOSIT( positObject, &srcImagePoints[0], FOCAL_LENGTH, criteria, rotation_matrix, translation_vector ); 

//calculate rotation angles 
double beta  = atan2((double)(-rotation_matrix[2]), (double)(sqrt(pow(rotation_matrix[0], 2) + pow(rotation_matrix[3], 2)))); 
double alpha = atan2((rotation_matrix[3]/cos(beta)),(rotation_matrix[0]/cos(beta))); 
double gamma = atan2((rotation_matrix[7]/cos(beta)),(rotation_matrix[8]/cos(beta)));
```

Comment: I really need help with posit, i just cant get it to work >.<

Comment: I am not exactly sure where the problem lies. But, I assume it is more of numerical error (inverse for singular matrix, round off error, etc.). You can try tracking, where the problem is becoming numerically instable. And is the smaller focal length, the correct one?

Comment: The smaller one is the correct one, yes. I started to get rid of posit, cause i read that it has problems with unknown depth, so i think my question is answered..